# Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.0

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I am trying to import project made by a friend in Android Studio and I am unable to import it reason being the gradle. While trying to configure it is showing this error

Gradle version 2.2 is required. Current version is 2.0. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in F:\callmeter-master\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.2-all.zip.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

I am new to Android studio Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be you can just update gradle version? latest version is 2.6
http://gradle.org/

Comment: Error:(14, 0) Cannot add rule ComponentModelBasePlugin.Rules#addSourceSetsOwnedByBinariesToTheirInputs for model element 'binaries' at state Mutated as this element is already at state GraphClosed.

Answer (score 3):

How's about doing what it says?

edit `F:\callmeter-master\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties` and replace `2.0` with `2.2`

Comment: There is no such file to perform this edit, maybe I don't get you so please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

Just do what it says, there's no reason not to update gradle.

You can install gradle to your machine with the latest version on [gradle.org](http://gradle.org), or since your friends project came with a wrapper, you can adjust the wrapper task like so in your `build.gradle` script:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.6' //Or desired version
}
```

And then execute `gradlew wrapper`to let it handle downloading and setting up the gradle client for you.  After that, execute tasks like normal.

Comment: Cannot add rule ComponentModelBasePlugin.Rules#addSourceSetsOwnedByBinariesToTheirInputs for model element 'binaries' at state Mutated as this element is already at state GraphClosed.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)